# Python Pandas - notnull() and ~notnull() are not mutually exclusive

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

When I run the following code:

```
maintenance_items['Last order'][maintenance_items['Last order'].notnull()].count()
```

I get an answer of 16522 (out of 19313). This seems to be correct. If I however use any of the following codes to check the opposite:

```
maintenance_items['Last order'][~maintenance_items['Last order'].notnull()].count()
```

or

```
maintenance_items['Last order'][maintenance_items['Last order'].isnull()].count()
```

or

```
maintenance_items['Last order'][maintenance_items['Last order'].isna()].count()
```

I get an answer of 0 (out of 19313). I was expecting 2791 (19313 minus 16522). Is there a sound reason why the notnull() and opposite statements above are not mutually exclusive?

Comment: Reading the documentation is helpful. [pandas.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) -> "Count __non-NA cells__ for each column or row. The values None, NaN, NaT, and optionally numpy.inf (depending on pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na) are considered NA." (emphasis mine). Therefore, `count` on any series of only `NaN` will be `0`. Perhaps you're looking for [pandas.DataFrame.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) or some similar way to get the total length of the subset.

Comment: That helps a lot, thankyou kindly. I changed from .count() to len() and now the answers are correct. Have a great day!